# Bind IEnumerable property of class to kendo mvc grid column

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

Let's imagine that we have a sample class looking like this:

```
public class ExampleDto
{
  public IEnumerable<PersonDto> Persons {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

View model looking like this:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
  public IEnumerable<ExampleDto> Examples {get; set;}
}
```

And binding to columns:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Title).Title("Title").Width(220)
                                .Filterable(true);
columns.Bound(c => c.Persons).Title("Persons").Width(180)
                                .Filterable(true)
```

What i want to obtain is to display in kendo grid column only names of persons - not whole object. Unfortunately that binding is not working - I have an error in console (jquery error) - "cannot read property "eq" of undefined". If i comment out lines with persons column definition everything works fine. What can I do to bind those property correctly?

Comment: Your view model looks like it's multi-dimensional. What should happen if one `ExampleDto` has multiple `Persons`? One row per person, with the same `Title` for each? You should restructure your view model for the grid that you are binding it to. That means the you would have one property for each column, and one row for each record that you want displayed. Assuming you are presenting as a simple grid and not some master/detail-type grid.

Comment: If one ExampleDto has multiple Persons I want to display names of this persons in one cell separated by comma.

Comment: Then add a string property of people, fill it with comma separated names, and bind *that* to the column

Comment: Ultimately, a view model should be shaped for the purpose that it will be viewed. This means that the same core 'model' might have multiple representations; one for a grid, one for a detail page, etc etc. It sometimes can feel like you are breaking DRY, but that's the way view models go.